# eclipse project terminates just 2 sec after it starts server

Tags: eclipse, gwt, project

Im new to gwt programming and I'm having an error that I can't solve.

Just after I run/debug my project, eclipse compiles everything and starts the server.

```
2011-03-10 10:39:51.193 java[315:a07] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled

2011-03-10 10:39:51.195 java[315:a07] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000

Initializing AppEngine server
Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger

Successfully processed /Users/goncalocoelho/Documents/workspace/Forms1/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml

Successfully processed /Users/goncalocoelho/Documents/workspace/Forms1/war/WEB-INF/web.xml
jetty-6.1.x
Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888
The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
```

2 sec after this, it just terminates the project without any error message (as if I pressed the Terminate button)

`<terminated> Forms1[Web Application] /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/Java`

Anyone experienced the same error/bug?

Comment: Have you tried running the project through the terminal, to debug any issue with your Eclipse installation?

Comment: no, can you explain me how to do that? or point me some directions? thanks

Comment: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html This should have what you need to get started without Eclipse. :)

Comment: c0elh0,
Did this behavior start for you after the recent JDK upgrade? It has for me.

Comment: yes it did! Did you found a work around? I'm trying to use webAppCreator to "fix" this problem for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google seems to be working on this issue](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/52bb64519bcb0605) which is related to the JVM upgrade on Mac OS X.
As a temporary workaround I was able to run in "Web Application" mode by going to the "Run Configuration" and changing the -d32 argument to -d64 (i.e. run in 64 bit mode) in the "VM arguments."

Answer (score 1):

I created a regular eclipse application runner (as if it were any other Java app) and copied the startup parameters from the GWT runner to my app runner.  After I replaced -d32 with -d64 and removed -XstartOnFirstThread my runner ran fine.  The problem seems to be that the GWT runners try to force those arguments.  Using a regular eclipse application runner prevents GWT from automatically using those parameters.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Chris! That seems to work :) I'll run some more tests but I think that is the way to go..
Did you get that behavior with the JDK upgrade? Cause Im convinced that that is the problem. Hope they fix that issue soon..

Comment: Chris, how can I create the "war" folder? Eclipse won't let me copy it between projects. I have to create it from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a workaround that works for me!!

I followed Neves tip: [code.google.com/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html)

and created the project with webAppCreator. Then I imported the project to eclipse and added the App Engine SDK Libraries to the project. Then I run it like a Java Application and the Development Mode is launched.

I really hope they will fix that bug..